# How to refer a undefined parameter in global scope

Tags: javascript

```
var a = 2;
function f(a) {return a;}
console.log(f(1));// return 1
console.log(f());// return undefined, but I want to make it return 2...
```

`f()` returns undefined, but I want to it refer the variable `a` in global scope. How could I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **[`arguments.length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments/length)** to test if a parameter was passed to the function:

```js
var a = 2;
function f(b) {
  if(arguments.length===1) return b;
  return a;
}

console.log(f(3));          //3
console.log(f(undefined));  //undefined
console.log(f(0));          //0
console.log(f());           //2
```

Answer (score 5):

```
var a = 2;
function f(b) {
    return b || a;
}
```

You need to use a different name for the function argument, else it's going to shadow the outer `a` and won't give you any chance to return it. Then it's a simple matter of deciding which value to return. Here I'm using a simple *falsey* check, you may or may not want to use something more detailed like `typeof b === 'undefined'` or such.

Comment: No. Ideally you should never have anything attached to `window`.

Comment: This will return `2` for `f(0)` and `f(false)`.  The `undefined` test helps, but using `arguments.length` would ensure that `b` is missing.

Comment: @RickHitchcock, _"Here I'm using a simple falsey check, you may or may not want to use something more detailed like typeof b === 'undefined' or such."_ does cover that :)

Comment: Agreed, but I think the test *should* be within the function rather than be optional.

Comment: @Rick I think that depends on the exact desired behaviour and is not something I'll speculate one... :)

Answer (score 1):

you could do something like this, which checks if the variable has been defined or not.

```
var a = 2;
function f(x) {
    return (typeof x==="undefined")? a : x;
}
console.log(f(1));// return 1
console.log(f());// return 2
```